# Add query string to local HTML files

Tags: ios, swift, http, nsurl

I have codes to load local html files (html files are inside the app, not from server), but how would I go about adding query string to it. I basically want to pass data from swift into html webview. Is this even possible? Alot of examples I've found is related to html files from server, but haven't found any for html files stored inside the app.

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension:"html", subdirectory: "www")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Answer (score 3):

**To add query string parameters to local URL for WebView you can use code below. It is valid for Xcode 9 and Swift 4.**

```
let bundleMainUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "www");
let fullUrl = URL(string: "?os=ios", relativeTo: bundleMainUrl);
let request = URLRequest(url: fullUrl!);
webView?.load(request);
```

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me on both iOS 11 and iOS 13.

Comment: Thanks, Mikep, This is the only solution work for me, +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by using Javascript. Check out `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

Answer (score 1):

If you have a full URL string with the queries, you can just initialise NSURL with that string.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: My html are stored locally inside the app, not from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSURLComponents` and `NSURLQueryItem` to construct a URL with query parameters:

```
var urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "www/index.html")!

urlComponents.queryItems = [
  NSURLQueryItem(name: "key1", value: "value1"),
  NSURLQueryItem(name: "key2", value: "value2")
]
urlComponents.URL // returns www/index.html?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Comment: The html files are stored locally on the app (not from server). So, if I use webView.loadRequest(urlComponents.URL) , i get an error message about expecting NSURLRequest type

Comment: Add the query items to the bundle's URL before passing it to `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: Not sure if I follow...can you provide the full source code to load local html files (index.html is stored inside a folder name WWW) with query string?

Comment: I showed you how to add query items to a URL.  Break the URL you already have (from the bundle) down into its components, add the query items, then turn those components back into a URL.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?                                                            let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "www/index.html")!
        
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            urlComponents.queryItems = [
                NSURLQueryItem(name: "os", value: "guile"),
                NSURLQueryItem(name: "appID", value: "hi")
            ]
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: urlComponents.URL!)
        
        webView.loadRequest(request) This code doesn't work.

Comment: The code you sent works fine for html files loaded from server, but I don't believe NSURLComponents will work for html files loaded from app or at least I haven't found any examples.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by using pathForResource instead of pathForResource as I was able to append string toward the end.

var url = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "www").stringByAppendingString("?os=ios")

Comment: It is not working for me because `url` is string and it can not be passed to webView load.